# Difference between Share Customer Accounts per website and global

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to Magento. working on magento 1.7 I need to implement DOB in registration form for that I went to Configuration-> Customer Configuration ->Name and Address Options and selected Show Date of Birth to optional. but it gave me error

> Cannot share customer accounts globally because some customer accounts
>   with the same emails exist on multiple websites and cannot be merged.

I changed Share Customer Accounts  to Per Website form Global. its a multi store so my question is **what effects it will have on my multi store from changing global to per website** ? any login issues or multiple email issue.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, account sharing in Magento is set on a per website level. This means that if you have created a multistore with several websites, a customer account can be used only on the website within the multistore for which the account was created. The customer won't be able to log in using that account on the other websites.

If you want to, you can make account sharing global. In this way a single customer account can be used to log in to any of the websites within the multistore no matter on which site the customer has registered.

Comment: i want to add DOB field in registration form without changing Share Customer Accounts to Per Website from global. any alternative solution

Comment: I was able to add DOB field from backed without changing to global. No error